# How to set shotcuts to toggle comments in vimrc file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to create a shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to toggle comment for .vhd files, so thing should be like this:

when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, in vim normal mode, it should add "-- " at the begining of the actual line.

I tried to add "nmap < C-c > <--space> " in my vimrc file,but it didn't work.

Comment: This is a common request. I would recommend looking for a [comment](https://vimawesome.com/?q=comment) plugin. I use [commentary.vim](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/commentary-vim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a plugin like [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary)

That said, you can achieve what you want with the following mapping:

```vim
nmap <C-c> I-- <esc>
```

Comment: This however, is not filtetype specific. Nothing against the answer, just for completeness

Comment: @L3viathan Thx for the answer, I installed the Nerd commenter plugin, it works but its comment short key is still set to "<leader>cc", but I want it to be "ctrl+c", do you have an idea?

Comment: @CongLi `nmap <C-c> <leader>cc`

Comment: This answer the question, but not really the title of the post which is toggling comments. That would be more like `nnoremap <expr> gcc getline('.') =~ '^-- ' ? '^3x' : 'I-- '`. However this should probably be a buffer-local mapping, doesn't accept a count, doesn't repeat with `.`, mutates registers, doesn't use `'commentstring'`, can not be used in visual mode or like an operator. TL;DR: stand on the shoulders of giants and [use a comment plugin](https://vimawesome.com/?q=comment).